# Adding views in a collapsingtoolbar layout

Tags: android

Is it possible to add views in collapsing toolbar expanded state? I would like to add a clickable button in middle of it and if possible show that button also in collapsed state. this is my code.

`

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/songdetailrecycler">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>`
```

Comment: by the way that code is wrapped by a CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

it is more complex example that i use in my app:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardfilter"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_filter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/filter" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/science" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: what happens if you set a click method for those imageviews? does it work as intended?